# Should I do both BJJ & Taek-won-do weekly?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, health

I’ve been practicing BJJ for a few months now.

Does anyone have any expertise with what’s best for gaining skill if both martial arts were to be combined weekly?

**Q: Should I continue my BJJ and bring Taek-won-do alongside my weekly training?**

Comment: This is a duplicate of the same question: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/can-i-do-brazilian-jiu-jitsu-and-tae-kwon-do-at-the-same-time/7917#7917

I would also point you to my answers here:

https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/can-i-do-brazilian-jiu-jitsu-and-tae-kwon-do-at-the-same-time/7917#7917
https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4865/pursuing-tae-kwon-do-and-karate-at-same-time/4867#4867

https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/training-two-martial-arts-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-days-of-the-week/5389#5389

Comment: Spelling - Tae Kwon Do, or Taekwondo. Tae is "foot" (implying "strike with foot"), Kwon is "hand", Do is "way" or "art" as in Japanese.